# ASP.NET MVC Possible to have an interface as model in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Say that I have the following interface:

```
public interface IUserListVM
{
     IList<string> UserList { get; }
}
```

and a view model implementing this view model interface:

```
public class UserListVM : IUserListVM
{
    private IList<string> userList = new List<string>();

    IList<string> UserList
    {
        get { return userList; }
    }
}
```

is it then possible to have a view that expects a model that inherits the IUserListVM.
Say that I have a UserList partial view that looks something like this:

```
 @model MVCWebsite.Views.IUserListVM

 @foreach (string user in Model.UserList) {
     user
 }
```

The meaning of this is to have partial views as standalone as possible.

Comment: Yes, but if you're main view does not need the data you are passing, the model is doing to much [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Instead you should be using [RenderAction](http://devproconnections.com/development/how-use-aspnet-mvc-render-action-helpers).

Answer (score 9):

After your edit - yes that is entirely possible. See [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vtxbSg)

Comment: As a note to improve on @Vladimiris answer, if you want to implement things like the Display annotations, they need to be applied to the interface

Comment: To which versions do this apply? I can only select.NET 4.7.2 in your fiddle so I'm wondering whether it applies to previous versions as well...?